# Cannot Add More Than One Item To Cart No Matter What I Try In PHP

Tags: php, session

I feel so ashamed that over a week now I still can't figure out how to insert a new item to cart, if user has clicked on it, and again if user have clicked the item earlier, i have to increment the quantity.

and  at last calculate quantity for each item, total number of items in the cart, amount for each item quantity, and total amount in cart.

My code only modifies the cart with details of the last clicked item.

```
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 100000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
$output;
if(isset($_POST['item']) && isset($_POST['price'])) {
    $_SESSION['purchase'] = ((isset($_SESSION['purchase'])) ? $_SESSION['purchase'] : 0);
    $item_array = array(
        $_POST['item'] => array(
            'item'            => $_POST['item'],
            'price'           => $_POST['price'],
            'quantity'        => 1  
        )
    );
    $purchasedItems = 0;
    $_SESSION['purchasedItems'] = $purchasedItems;
    if(!isset($_POST['action']) && !isset($_POST['action'])) {  
        if(isset($_SESSION['purchase'])) {
            $available = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['purchase'] as $key => $value) {//ERROR: invalid argument supplid for foreach loop
                if($value == $_POST['item']) {
                    $available++;
                    foreach($value as $a => $b) {
                        $_SESSION['purchase'][$key]['quantity'] = $b['quantity'] + 1;               
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $_SESSION['purchase'][$item_array] = $item_array;
                }               
            }
            foreach($_SESSION['purchase'][$item_array] as $k => $v) {//ERROR: invalid argument supplied for foreach loop
                if($_SESSION['purchase'][$v] == $_POST['item']) {   
                }
            }
            if($available < 1) {
            $_SESSION['purchase'] = $item_array;    
            } else {
                $_SESSION['purchase'] = $item_array; 
            }
        }
    }    
    $total = 0;     
    foreach($_SESSION['purchase'] as $key => $value) {//ERROR: invalid argument supplied for foreach loop
        $total = $total + ($value['quantity'] * $value['price']);       
        print '<table><tr><th>Products </th><th> Quantity &nbsp;&nbsp</th><th>Price&nbsp;&nbsp</th><th> Total &nbsp;&nbsp</th><th> Actions </th></tr>';
        print '<tr><td>' . "" . $value['item'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value['quantity'] . "" . '</td>' . '<td>' . number_format($value['quantity'] * $value['price'], 2) . '</td></tr>';
}   
    print '<tr><td> Total Price &nbsp;&nbsp</td><td>' . "" . $total . '</td></tr>'; 
    print '<tr><td> Total Number Of Items &nbsp;&nbsp</td><td>' . "" . count($_SESSION['purchase']) . '</td></tr></table>';
    var_dump($_SESSION['purchase']);
    print $_SESSION['purchase']; // ERROR: array to string conversion   
    print session_status(); 
}
?>
```

Here I have included the errors thrown in their corresponding code lines.

Comment: FYI, you are double checking the post action: !isset($_POST['action']) && !isset($_POST['action'])

Answer (score 1):

Some feedback:

- You should not get (trust) price from _POST.
- And you probably shouldn't build a custom array in _POST.
- And to me, 'cart' rather than 'purchase' would make more sense reading the code.
- Just build an array with item'nos as keys and qty as values. Add value if itemno / key already exits.

**Sketch**

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_REQUEST['item'])) die();
//sanitize indata. here we'll only accept ints.
$item = floor($_REQUEST['item']);
//assume we're sending quantity as well
$qty = 1;
if (isset($_REQUEST['qty'])) $qty = floor($_REQUEST['qty']);
//maybe some more sanity here, negative values etc..
//
//check if we need to initialize cart
if (!is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
//
//either add item as new key or increase value of quantity
if (in_array($item, array_keys($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    //add qty
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item]['qty'] += $qty;
} else {
    //init
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = array();
    //setup a pointer for easier code
    $a = &$_SESSION['cart'][$item];
    $a['qty'] = $qty;
    //look up price and name for the item in backend
    $rec = [select Price, Name from bla bla where ItemNo=$item]
    $a['price'] = $rec['Price'];
    $a['name'] = $rec['Name'];
    //actually, you would probably like to verify that item actually exists in database before even init the array so swap above..
}

//calc totals
$total = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] $item=>$itemRec) {
    $total += $itemRec['qty'] * $itemRec['price'];
}
```

Comment: please can you edit the code with your corrections and send me link or via email cuz i am confused at this

Comment: BIG thank you @Tenson. Thanks for helping out. I would adapt it to suit my script.

Comment: Please consider marking my post as the accepted answer. And good luck with your php-career!

Comment: Please @Tenson how can I make a post the accepted answer that on here? I really don't know how. thanks.

Comment: @smacaz, There should be a gray checker-mark to the top-left of my answer. You can click it and it will turn green.